# Reflections 0.10.1 and 0.10.2 broken for ClassLoaders?

Tags: java, reflections

I have some existing code which uses `Reflections` like this:

```
    ClassLoader myClassLoader = MyClassUtils.getMyClassLoader();
    // above call returns a URLClassLoader
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(myClassLoader);
```

This code was working fine up until version `0.9.12`

However, its breaking in versions `0.10.1` and `0.10.2`.

On checking the sources, I found that in `ConfigurationBuilder` class of `0.9.12`, there was this logic in `build` method of `ConfigurationBuilder`:

```
else if (param instanceof ClassLoader) { /* already taken care */ }
```

However, this has been removed in the future versions. Because of this, if the params are instance of `ClassLoader` it throws `ReflectionsException`.

Can anyone please guide if the way we use this has changed ?

Thanks!